# Объединение таблицы типа один ко многим

Tags: sql, sql-server

Столкнулся с проблемой объединения таблицы вида один ко многим с таблицей значений. Не знаю, как правильно сформулировать вопрос, поэтому приведу для примера таблицы. Есть таблица один ко многим вида

```
| n | v |
---------
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 1 | z |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | z |
| 3 | y |
```

И просто таблица уникальных значений вида

```
| t |
-----
| x |
| y |
| z |
```

И на выходе я хочу получить таблицу вида

```
| n | v | t |
-------------
| 1 | x | x |
| 1 | y | y |
| 1 | z | z |
| 2 | x | x |
| 2 | - | y |
| 2 | z | z |
| 3 | - | x |
| 3 | y | y |
| 3 | - | z |
```

Где прочерки это NULL. Грубо говоря, мне надо объединить две таблицы друг с другом таким образом, чтобы объединение происходило для каждого уникального номера n отдельно. Использовать цикл для каждого уникального n и делать join по отдельности не хотелось бы, так как объем данных большой (и в перспективе станет в разы больше), а циклы в MSSQL работают слишком медленно. Также я пытался решить проблему с помощью рекурсивного CTE, но у меня выходила неадекватаная таблица. Быть может кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей и\или знает какое-то лаконичное решение. Извините за кривой вопрос и спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct t1.n, tt1.v, t2.t 
from   t1 
left   join t2 on 1 = 1 
left   join t1 as tt1 
on     t2.t=tt1.v 
and    t1.n=tt1.n
order  by t1.n -- если нужна сортировка
```